# Swift Tableview Cell for row at index

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8.1

how to write this code in swift .
 NSString *ss=[[[Arr valueForKey:@" " ] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@""];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ss: NSString = Arr.valueForKey(" ").objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("")
```

Basically the syntax for variable assignment is

```
let exampleVar:Type = Assignee
```

and to use a function in swift, you just use the syntax

```
receiver.aFunction(parameter)
```

Hope this helps. You could look the swift programming guide at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Also, to help further, perhaps you could explain more about the context of your code. For instance, what is Arr? If its an array, I don't think it has the function valueForKey. If its an NSDictionary (which I suspect it is), you will need to force unwrap it or use optional binding to make sure that the return value is not nil, else you will be faced with a exception.

Forcing an optional to unwrap looks like this:

```
let ss: NSString = Arr.valueForKey(" ")!.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)!.valueForKey("")!
```

and optional binding looks like this

```
var ss:NSString = ""
if let cellInfoArray = Arr.valueForKey(" ") as? NSArray{
    if let rowDict = cellInfoArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary{
        if let resultString = rowDict.valueForKey("") as? NSString{
            ss = resultString
        }else{
            //resultString if rowDict is nil
        }
    }else{
        //handle if rowDict is nil
    }
}else{
    //handle if cellInfoArray is nil
}
```

Hope this helps! (btw, not so good practice for object instances variable name to have first letter caps i.e. Arr. Its more of convention to be camel case with first letter as small letter like thisVariable.)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can right this way:

let ss: NSString = Arr.valueForKey("").objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("")